# How to read the next page on API using python?

Tags: python, api, pagination

I need help on how to do a loop so each time I make a GET request, it will always be the new page from the API.

I start with getting the first response. It includes a parameter to the next page `next_key`

```
{
  "result": [
    {
      ...,
      ...
    }
  ],
  "next_key": 123
 }
```

Below is my current attempt

```
import requests
import json

url = "https://flespi.io/gw/channels/all/messages"
headers = {"Authorization": "FlespiToken 23ggh45"}

def getFirst():
    data = {"limit_count":100, "limit_size":10000}
    params = {"data":json.dumps(data, separators=(",", ":"))}

    reqFirst = requests.get(url, params=params, headers=headers).json()
    return reqFirst["next_key"] ## this returns "123"

def getDataNext():
    data = {"limit_count":100, "limit_size":10000, "curr_key":getFirst()}
    params = {"data":json.dumps(data, separators=(",", ":"))}

    reqNext = requests.get(url, params=params, headers=headers)

    jsonData = reqNext.json()

    while True:
        if "next_key" in jsonData:
            data = {"limit_count":100, "limit_size":10000,"curr_key":jsonData["next_key"]}
            params = {"data":json.dumps(data, separators=(",", ":"))}

            req = requests.get(url, params=params, headers=headers).json()  ## this should do GET request for the third page and so on...

            print req["next_key"] # this returns "3321" which is the value for "next_key" in second page

        else:
            pass

getDataNext()
```

The full url including limit count, limit size and curr key is as follows `https://flespi.io/gw/channels/all/messages?data=%7B%22curr_key%22%123%2C%22limit_count%22%3A100%2C%22limit_size%22%3A10000%7D`

As you can see this only returns the second page that is `jsonData["next_key"]`. What I want to do is that for each GET request, the program will read the `next_key` and put it on the next GET request.

I am thinking to use increment on the `curr_key` but the key is random and also I do not know how many page there is.

I believe there must be just a simple solution for this but apparently I could not think about it. Thank you for your help and suggestion.

Comment: We have no access to the API or it's docs, how should we give advise? And what is the actual problem with your approach?

Comment: You need to either dynamically create the URL or adjust the headers depending on how the website accepts the page number.  With more information we should be able to easily do this.  Where does the website expect to find the page number? Can you share the website?

Comment: Hi Klaus, thank you for your comment. First of all, I don't think providing the access to the API or its docs is important here as my current problem with my approach here is that I can't get it to do GET request for next page. With my current attempt, it stop on second page only. I will edit my question to include some other information like the url

Comment: @Farmer Joe , I have edited my question. While the url is real,the token still not the real one but I hope it can help. Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this

```
has_next_key = False
nextKey = ""

if "next_key" in jsonData:
    has_next_key = True
    nextKey = jsonData["next_key"]

while has_next_key:
    data = {"limit_count":100, "limit_size":10000,"curr_key":nextKey}
    params = {"data":json.dumps(data, separators=(",", ":"))}

    req = requests.get(url, params=params, headers=headers).json()  ## this should do GET request for the third page and so on...
    if "next_key" in req:
        nextKey = req["next_key"]
        print nextKey # this returns "3321" which is the value for "next_key" in second page
    else:
        has_next_key = False
        # no next_key, stop the loop
```

Comment: Thank you. your answer works for me. Can you explain to me what is the difference between your answer and my code? Why do I need to put the `if` block outside `while` block?

Comment: using `while True:` you're doing loop with no ending, it repeat the request with same `next_key` because `jsonData` is never get new value so you will never reach third page. `if` in `while` block is used to set  `nextKey` and and check if we need to continue the loop or not ( `has_next_key`)